# Getting a BSOD when installing windows xp

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, bsod, multi-boot

I have installed Windows 7 on my laptop. Now I want to install Windows XP. How will I be able to pull this off without using Windows XP mode or any virtualization solution so that I could dual boot 7 and XP?I always get a BSOD when trying to boot up the XP installation CD.
I got this on Nirsoft's BSOD viewer:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Could it be your harddrive is set as SATA drive? You need to set it to Compatibility mode to boot with XP, or slipstream a SATA driver to a new XP CD